# Number of ways of picking cards from a shuffled deck.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, card-games

We are given 10 cards numbered - 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5. Wherein card with same number are identical. We shuffled the card and kept them in two boxes. We kept the first 5 cards in box 1 and next 5 cards in box 2.

Now we have to find the number of ways in which we can draw the card from the boxes. Our procedure of drawing is picking 1 card each from each box. Just for clarification, we draw it like-

One card from box1

One card from box2

One card from box1

One card from box2

One card from box1

One card from box2

One card from box1

One card from box2

One card from box1

One card from box2.

I've made some progress in the question. There would be three cases of picking the card in the box.

Case 1- 2 pair of card are same in box 1 and box 2 together.

Case 2−1 pair of card is same in box 1 and box 2 together.

Case 3- all cards are different in both the box.

Number of ways of drawing card in each case is. Case1−(5!∗5!)/(2!∗2!)(2!∗2!), Case2−(5!∗5!)(2!∗2!), Case3−(5!∗5!).

But I'm not understanding how to go further and what to do with these. So I want the answer till the end of it. Plz help. I suppose that I will get an answer instead of suggestion.

Comment: When you say number of ways, it is confusing in this case. Are you looking for different arrangements you can get from drawing the cards in the sequence (box1, card1), (box2, card1), (box1, card2), (box2,card2) ...?

Comment: Given that the cards are shuffled, what matters here is which card is selected in which position.  Choose two positions for the $1$s, two of the remaining positions for the $2$s, and so forth.